# Load data into Hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I need to load data in to Hbase using Mapreduce, How I need to start with Hbase, to integrate Hbase with Java do I need to use any jar file.

1. What are the jar files Required For Hbase to integrate with MapReduce
2. What are the APIs which I need to refer
3. How to code in Java for MapReduce

Comment: Better to use Pig script to access Hbase.using pig script we can call Java user defined functions. http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/tutorial.html For loading CSV files this link may be help you. http://www.rotanovs.com/hbase/hbase-importexport/

Comment: I want things in Map Reduce, not in Pig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Access Hbase from java, use below code:

```
conf = new HBaseConfiguration();        
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "ip1,ip2,ip3");
conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml"));
hbase = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
```